# How to display UpdateProgress at the center of a grid view with CSS?

Tags: asp.net, css, webforms, updatepanel, updateprogress

Need to display Update Progress at the center of a Grid view placed in a Ajax Update Panel. Is there a way to place the Update progreass control at the center of the grid view (or else center of the page) with CSS (without using jQuery or Java Script)?

Comment: We'll need to see some code, then we can better help you. Live examples are golden too :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the grid-view and update progress html within a wrapper div. Position div relatively and position the update progress absolutely at center.

See this jsfiddle that I have set up: http://jsfiddle.net/DDdyU/

key styles are

```
.wrapper
{
    position: relative;
}
.updateProgress
{
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-right: -20px;
}
```

negative margins are half size of update-progress.

Answer (score -1):

Not with just pure CSS unless you [absolutely position](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) the UpdateProgess div in the middle of the GridView. I feel like jQuery would be cleaner if you can use it in your application.